# Как заполнить массив своего типа данных С++

Tags: c++

Возможно я делаю большую глупость. Извините за неточные объяснения

Главная задача в том, что бы создать массив своего типа данных. Затем заполнить его целочисленными значениями.

Я создал свой класс TDV. Объявил в нём массив R типа TDV.
Как мне присвоить элементам массива значения типа int?
Я новичок и только учусь,но информацию на форумах не нашёл или не понял, что нашёл то, что нужно.

<h файл>

```
class TDV {
private:
  int n;
  TDV* R;

public: 
  TDV();
  ~TDV();
  int DV();
```

<cpp файл>

```
TDV::TDV() {
  
  R = new TDV[n];

}

TDV::~TDV() 
{
    delete[]R;
}


int TDV::DV()
{
  
 
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    R[i] = 1;
  }
```

Есть код на C#, там без проблем присваиваю этой строкой

```
R[i] = rnd.Next(-150, 150);
```

Comment: я правильно понимаю что внутри класса X есть указатель на класс X и вы внутри одного экземпляра класса X создаёте массив из N экземпляров класса X, каждый из которых еще создадут такие массивы?

Comment: вы бы точнее описали, что именно вам нужно, т.е. какая задача изначально?

Comment: Главная задача в том, что бы создать массив своего типа данных. Затем заполнить его целочисленными значениями.

Comment: т.е. вы хотите например заполнить массив строк целыми числами? это как?
в данном случае произвольный тип TDV как-то прировнять целому числу?

Comment: Я понимаю, что у меня ошибка. И я  примерно понимаю в чем. Как бы вы сделали? Возможно код, который выше - полный бред. Я соглашусь. Но как правильно? Мне потом нужно сделать перегрузку операторов для массива(+, /, <, >)

Comment: Во-первых Ваш "свой тип данных", он что из себя представляет? Каждый тип данных отражает какой-то объект. Например `int` представляет целые числа, `double` – дробные и т.д. Что представляет Ваш тип `TDV`?

Comment: Мой тип представляет  целочисленные данные.

Comment: Чем тогда Ваш тип отличается от `int`, например? И да, если отвечаете на мой комментарий, ставьте @ и мой ник вначале, чтобы я получал уведомление.

Comment: В приведенном коде тип представляет пользовательский класс TDV. Кроме того, приведенный код ну никак не соответствует C#.

Comment: Ваш тип хранит указатель на массив объектов таких же типов и хранит размер этого массива. Тут  вопрос: "вы хотите чтобы в этом массиве все  TDV  хранили указатель на массив разных размеров?  Хорошо, если в этом разобрались, но еще нужно и представление вашего класса. Если это int, то он должен хранить объект типа int, как свое представление. А тип размера массива или еще чего то всегда выбирайте из без знаковых типов. Чтобы не возникали вопросы, нужно в своем вопросе четко рассказать что хотите получать в  результате.

Answer (score 1):

Вот у вас есть тип

```
 class TDV
 {
 private:
    int n;
 public: 
    TDV();
   ~TDV();
 }
```

Который представляет целочисленные данные, содержа в себе фундаментальный целочисленный тип данных `int`. (Для чего вы так делаете оставим пока в стороне).

Теперь вам нужно заполнить массив этим классом, можно сделать так:

```
 std::vector<TDV> v;
 v.push_back(TDV());
 v.push_back(TDV());
```

теперь у вас вектор из двух элементов типа `TDV`. Или можно так:

```
 TDV* v = new TDV[2];
 v[0] = TDV();
 v[1] = TDV();
 //do smth
 delete[] v;
```

Теперь как сделать так чтобы ваш класс `TDV` содержал определенное число? Сейчас при инициализации объекта типа `TDV` он инициализируется мусором.  Если переписать конструктор так:

```
   TDV(int value)
   {
       n = value;
   }
```

То можно уже писать так:

```
 TDV* v = new TDV[2];
 v[0] = TDV(1);
 v[1] = TDV(2);
 //do smth
 delete[] v;
```

Comment: спасибо буду пробовать)